Why is command nogltOffset (langsci-gb4e) not working in Overleaf
This manual for the package langsci-gb4e discusses a command nogltOffset which removes space between an interlinear gloss and its translation.  It includes the following block of code which demonstrates this:
\ea
\gll Dit is een zin. \\
this is a sentence\\
\glt ‘This translation has standard vertical space . ’
\z
\nogltOffset
\ea
\gll Dit is een zin . \\
this is a sentence\\
\glt ‘This translation has less vertical space.’
\z
\resetgltOffset
\ea
\gll Dit is een zin . \\
this is a sentence\\
\glt ‘This translation has standard vertical space again.’
\z

The manual provides an example output in which the middle gloss, the one for which nogltOffset has been applied, has less space between the gloss and the translation.  However, when I load the package in Overleaf (\usepackage{langsci-gb4e}) and copy in this code, I don't see any difference in the glosses when I hit "Recompile".  I'm somewhat new to Latex/Overleaf and I'm using a template to write proceedings for a conference, so it's possible something in the other files is clashing with langsci-gb4e. Any ideas as to why the command isn't working?

welcome! can you complete your code so we can compile it to reproduce the problem? note that overleaf is almost certainly irrelevant here - it's just your editor. try the code in a new document with a standard class such as article. can you reproduce the issue there?

It looks like the issue goes away if I use a new document with article class. (This is with inputting the code block above, along with \usepackage{langsci-gb4e} in the preamble.) The issue also goes away if I use a new document with langscibook, the class for the template that I'm using.  So it might be an issue with the template itself, and the files the conference had us download.  I wouldn't be able to share all the files all here, but I will look into them to try and figure out what the conflict might be!

basically, the procedure is to make a copy of your project and remove everything you can without eliminating the problem. then post whatever is left.
